# Button and Footer

Tags: css

I am having trouble with a button and footer in my app.

I am trying to style it so the button sits on the footer when in the mobile platform like [mobile][1].

and then when in desktop platforms the button moves to the left with this blue border, like [desktop][2]

See links to images at the bottom.

My code is as below:

```css
.btn-default-finish {
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 48px;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #002b80;
}

footer {
  background-color: #0032a0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 114px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <a href="{{ path('confirm-booking') }}" class="btn btn-default-finish btn-lg btn-block mt-10" type="button">
    <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>Make booking</a>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="row" id="footer-details">

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: is this below code what u expecting??

Comment: Yes for when it is in mobile platform but when it is on desktop the button needs to move to another column to the right to the appointment selections like in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML

  <footer>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <a href="{{ path('confirm-booking') }}" class="btn btn-default-finish btn-lg btn-block mt-10" type="button">
    <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>Make booking</a>
</div>

  <div class="row" id="footer-details">

  </div>
</footer>

    CSS
    .btn-default-finish {
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 48px;
      background-size: cover;
      color: #002b80;
    }

    footer {
      background-color: #0032a0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 114px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does put the button in the footer for mobile, which is great thank you, but it also keeps it in there for desktop. The button needs to move to the right of the card as shown in the second image.

Comment: image is invisible.

Comment: above code in medium md and in large screen  lg the button aligned right side.

Comment: when it is on desktop the button needs to move to another column to the right to the appointment selections like in the image above